# CSS Menu align right

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm new to HTML/CSS and also this dropdown menu. I tried putting `align="right"` on its div container but nothing's happening.. It just made my header look unorganized.

The menu is supposed to be at the top of the blue horizontal line and below the logo. It was organized at first until I made changes to header.html to create a dropdown menu.

Here's my HTML code for that:

HTML

CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif; 
}

div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 90%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    min-width:800px;
    width: 800px;
}

#left-panel, #right-panel {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        display:inline-block;
        width:30em;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
        min-width:100px;
        background:white;
        overflow:hidden;
}
.header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.footer, .push  {
    width:800px;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}

p.copyright {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.text-image{
    width:533px;
    height:321px;
    background-image: url('images/about-cti.jpg'); 
    background-position: 350px 250px; 
}

.a {
        text-align: left;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 11pt;
        text-decoration: none; 
        color : #000000;
} 
<!--Navigation-->
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  left: -1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;  
  *width: 100%; /* IE7 hack*/
}
#cssmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
<!--End of Navigation-->
```

Comment: if you want it under the logo, you have to float it to the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
#cssmenu{
    float:right;
}
```

and remove

```
align="right"
```

Comment: Or maybe I'll just add `<br />` until it goes down. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `<br />` the solution because it goes below too much like there's an excess whitespace.. I tried adding `margin-top` and `top` properties on the horizontal div but it's not working.

Comment: try to use this code.. for html http://pastebin.com/sg3N8DdW and this for css http://pastebin.com/fWqE81W3 but you have to clean up the css. hope this works edit: add padding-top:20px; to #main css file

Comment: ahh you want the menu direct under the searchfield?

Answer (score 1):

I think your CSS is all messed up. For now give :

```
#cssmenu {
 float:right;
}
```

and for the div below that (with border:collapse) give :

```
clear:both;
```

I think, this the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/DWqsH/

`float:right` `add` in this `below class`

```
#cssmenu {
float:right;

}
```